# LDAP Queries using Pattern Matching

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible with LDAP queries to filter on patterns similar to Regular Expressions?  For example, to find all computer objects with names that match "ABC-nnnnnn" where "n" is a numeric digit and only those with 6-digits?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge LDAP only supports wildcards, like:

```
(CN=ABC-*)
```

That'll grab anything that starts with `ABC-`. You would probably have to further filter the results using something else like PowerShell, or programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no capability to do this aside from the wildcard suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP search filters do not support the concept of pattern matching, but they do support the
concept of *ordering*. LDAP clients should consult the schema programmatically to determine which ordering rules
are used for attributes, and if an appropriate ordering rule is supported, a combination of
`greaterOrEqual` and `lessOrEqual` filter components in a compound filter might work. Whether or
not the results are as expected depends completely on the ordering rules.

For example:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
  -b basedn -s scope \
  `(&(cn>=abc-000000)(cn<=abc-999999))` attribute_list
```

As above, whether this returns the expected results depends on the ordering rules. Consult your friendly neightborhood LDAP admin for help with ordering rules and schema.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Protocol search request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5.1)
- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: I tried the ordering approach, but it's still not getting the correct count.  Example: "select distinguishedName,name from LDAP://DC=home,DC=local where objectCategory='computer' AND operatingSystem='Windows 7*' AND cn>='ABC-000000' AND cn<='ABC-999999'"   - I am using ADsDSOobject for the query. NOt sure if that hampers this effort or not.